# How can I update singular value of Array in React State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating my event handler to allow voting which is stored in an Array state in React but I'm stuck.

I have tried to use another array for updating then using setState with the new array after some research but it is not correct

```
 const App = props => {
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
 let [votes, setVotes] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
 let newArray = [...votes];
 const handleVote = () => {
  newArray[selected] += 1;
  setVotes([newArray]);
   }; 
 return (
   <div>
     <div>{props.anecdotes[selected]} </div>
     <div>has {votes[selected]} votes</div>

     <div>
       <Button onClick={handleVote()} text="vote" />
       <Button onClick={randomAnecdote} text="next anecdote" />
     </div>
  </div>
   );
   };
```

Expected to increase the value of votes[0] where I used 0 as selected from state to increase by one but I am getting an infinite loop. ALso previously just got 1 added to the end of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating Votes**

The issue with your `handleVote` method is that when you call `setVotes`, you call it like this: `setVotes([newArray])`, passing `[newArray]` as the argument. So on the first pass you'll set `votes` to `[[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]` and then on the second pass you'll get `votes[0]`, which is `[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and add `1` to it, which will result in string concatenation, so you get `["2,2,3,4,5,61"]` as `newArray`.

To fix this, change `setVotes([newArray])` to `setVotes(newArray)`.

**Infinite Loop**

You're setting the `onClick` prop of the vote button equal to the output of `handleVote` rather than equal to `handleVote` itself. So you're calling `handleVote` when you define the vote button's `onClick` prop. So on every render `handleVote` gets called immediately, updates state, and triggers a rerender—hence the infinite loop.

You can fix this by changing:

```js
<Button onClick={handleVote()} text="vote" />
```

to:

```js
<Button onClick={handleVote} text="vote" />
```

Comment: Thanks! that stopped the loop :) But my code is still not working as I want, my first array becomes [2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] then ["2,2,3,4,5,61"], what can I do please